# How does a constructor choose a base class constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

If you are inside the constructor of a derived class, and you make no explicit call to the base class constructor, how does the compiler know which base constructor to use?

Comment: It uses the default constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a base class is not mentioned in the constructor [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), it will be [default initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization). Since the base class will definitely be of class type, that means that the [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) will be called.

Two of those references also have examples of derived classes which implicitly call the base class default constructor. For instance:

```
struct Class : public Base
{
    unsigned char x;
    unsigned char y;

    Class ( int x )
      : Base ( 123 ), // initialize base class
        x ( x ),      // x (member) is initialized with x (parameter)
        y { 0 }       // y initialized to 0
    {}                // empty compound statement

    Class ( double a )
      : y ( a+1 ),
        x ( y ) // x will be initialized before y, its value here is indeterminate
    {} // base class constructor does not appear in the list, it is
       // default-initialized (not the same as if Base() were used, which is value-init)

   ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It uses the default constructor, as mandated by the standard in N4140 *Initializing bases and members*, §12.6.2 [class.base.init]/8 (emphasis mine):

> In a non-delegating constructor, if a given potentially constructed subobject is not designated by a *mem-initializer-id*
>   (including the case where there is no *mem-initializer-list* because the constructor has no *ctor-initializer*),
>   then
>
> - if the entity is a non-static data member that has a *brace-or-equal-initializer* and either
>
>   - the constructor’s class is a union, and no other variant member of that union is designated by a *mem-initializer-id* or
>   - the constructor’s class is not a union, and, if the entity is a member of an anonymous union, no other member of that union is designated by a *mem-initializer-id*,
>
>   the entity is initialized as specified in 8.5;
> - otherwise, if the entity is an anonymous union or a variant member, no initialization is performed;
> - **otherwise, the entity is default-initialized**.

Note that base classes are potentially constructed subobjects per *Special member functions*, §12 [special]/5:

> For a class, its non-static data members, its non-virtual direct base classes, and, if the class is not abstract, its virtual base classes are called its potentially constructed subobjects.